# DataTables - Remove DataTables from HTML Table created in different JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

So I have a site I visit everyday for work. The [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) implementation on this site is atrocious. The DataTable is applied to an HTML table that is generated when the page is rendered and then the DataTable is initialized on it. I figured this is great because I can create a little `TamperMonkey` script to remove the horrible DataTable and create one that functions how I need it to.

The DataTable is created via inline `Javascript` at the end of the document `body`. I tried the following per the [DOCs](http://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) for the `destory()` method.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       
// @version    0.1
// @description  Makes the Invoice Table more user friendly
// @include      URL
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require  http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

// @copyright  2014+, Me
// ==/UserScript==
$(function() {
   var t = $('#customer_invoices').DataTable();
   t.destroy();

});
```

It does not "*remove those enhancements and return the table to its original un-enhanced state, with the data shown in the table*" as stated in the docs. It does not appear to do anything.

I think it is either because the table has not been Datatable initialized yet, or that I am not able to access the original DataTable initialization in a different scope.

Any help is greatly appreciated as this has me banging my head on the desk.

Comment: Have you considered clearing all of the class / id names inside of the table, thus restoring it to a generic html table?

Comment: @Eclecticist I have not as the DT initialization also adds the parameter `bVisible` to some rows. I hope to get those rows visible again when I destroy the DT.

Comment: the element has already been turned into a data table element, so you wouldn't need to call `dataTable()` (note the camel case)... it would be a matter of accessing the `destroy` method on the object already in memory.  I'm tinkering and will post an answer if I find out how.  You also would probably want to bind a custom event listener that calls destroy on an element when the dataTable is called to make sure you are calling destroy after the initialization of the element's dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible using the `.destroy()` method.

If you open up a console, you would typically be able to do this by running:

```
$("#elementID").dataTable.destroy()
```

*note:  I did not use `dataTable().destroy()` because the element is already a dataTable.*

However, the issue you are running into is that no `destroy` method exists... because the dataTable source code has been minified, and is no longer called `destroy`... but rather given a token name with a much smaller footprint (probably b or c d or something like that).

The only way to do what you want will be to physically alter the properties of the element that make it into a dataTable... or to look for a map file for the minified file, which could allow you to find which minified function reference should be called instead of `destroy()` to get the desired effect.

Comment: If I use a unminified version on my script will it work? I don't get an error regarding the `destroy` method in my console which would be the case no? I am thinking about accessing the data object within DT and recreating the table from scratch.

Comment: hard to say... it depend on whether the DT source code checks for an existing implementation on a given element before returning the implementing the feature on the element.  Your best bet is to try to use prototype to re-implement the functionality on DataTable you want with the method name you want, and then just call  `destroy` on any datatable element.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative you can have is to take clone of your div before doing any changes.And after doing changes replace that div with the clone.